# Bad symbols on my eclipse C++ installation

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support

I come from that website.

I have a C++ project that compiles with g++-4.8 without problems. I just wanted to use std::int8_t from the cstdint file.

Problem is the eclipse indexer can't resolve the name.

I went to the csdint file and in the initial macro it expands __cplusplus to 199711L instead of 201103L.

In my project settings I added std=c++11 and in the compiler flags I addded **GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X**

And did I say it compiles?

It's very frustrating, I suppose I can live without the indexer, but then again what is the purpose of an IDE if it's giving me error false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/490066/

Go to Project Properties->Paths and Symbols->Symbols Tab->GNU C++->__cplusplus Symbol and change to 201103L

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your used type of C++ project and your eclipse version. I have a Makefile project in Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5) with CDT 8.8.1.201602051005) If you have a Makefile project and see the item `C/C++ General`-->`C/C++ Make Projects` in your project properties, you also have to go to the tab "Discovery Options" and add `-std=c++11` to the **Compiler invocation arguments**.

Comment: `-stc=c++11` was necessary for compilation, but compilation was not the problem, only the symbols, for this it needed the path to the Symbols in `Project Properties->Paths and Symbols->Symbols Tab->GNU C++->__cplusplus Symbol`